# Два или несколько вопросов в одном

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, новые-участники

В Stack Overflow на русском по моему вероятностному суждению новые участники нередко в один вопрос вмещают два или несколько порой мало связанных между собой вопросов. Пример:

- [Описание сайта в поисковиках](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468428/199934)

Полагаю, что смогу дать полезный ответ на первую часть вопроса, поскольку сам сталкивался с проблемой, обращался на форум для вебмастеров Google и разрешил её. Правильным будет мой ответ или нет — решит сообщество, речь сейчас не о его сути. Но по второй части вопроса не имею представлений, т. к. никогда не пользовался Linkedln.

Понимаю, что лучше:

- Просить новичков задавать каждый вопрос отдельно,
- Отвечать сразу на все поставленные вопросы,
- Попробовать разобраться с Linkedln и дать ответ на побочный вопрос.

Но можно ли дать ответ **только** на какой-то один из вопросов, если их несколько? В данном примере я хочу ответить на первую часть вопроса, но не на побочный вопрос. Как к этому отнесётся сообщество?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Хороший вопрос - залог хорошего ответа](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2487/181472)

Answer (score 11):

Тезисно выражу своё мнение:

- В каждом вопросе-публикации должен содержаться один основной вопрос — проблема или задача.

  > Как правильно забивать гвозди?
- Разумеется, нормально, если проблема выражена в нескольких вопросительных предложениях.

  > Как забивать гвозди? Есть ли специализированный инструмент?
- Плохо, если в вопросе несколько мало связанных проблем. Такой вопрос следует автору — разбить на несколько атомарных, а проверяющим участникам — закрыть и переоткрыть после разделения.

  > Как забивать гвозди? Как их выдёргивать? Я пилил доску с гвоздями, но теперь пила сломалась, что делать? Посоветуйте хороший травмпункт. Кстати, познакомлюсь с симпатичной девушкой, у которой папа — столяр.

Comment: Если до автора вопроса проблематично достучаться, может, лучше не закрывать вопросы, а самостоятельно создавать новые (при условии, что они соответствуют тематике сайта)? Правда, проблема: вопросы, в отличие от ответов, здесь, видимо, нельзя помечать «общими».

Comment: @СашаЧерных если очень нужно, то можно оставить тревогу для модератора с просьбой пометить вопрос общим. Однако к общему вопросу все ответы автоматически становятся общими. Это не очень честно по отношению к авторам ответов.

Comment: Такой вариант придумал: создать клона → уведомить остальных пользователей в профиле, что это дополнительная учётка такого-то пользователя, созданная сугубо для технических задач, → переносить побочные вопросы с неё. Таким образом репутация основного аккаунта переносящего не изменится, а отвечающие смогут получать баллы за свои ответы.

Comment: @СашаЧерных слишком много движений

Comment: @СашаЧерных час работы менеджера сообщества (у модератора не хватит прав) ради сомнительной пользы для человека, который может больше никогда не вернуться. Можно проще: задать вопрос от своего имени и оставить ссылку. Если автору нужно ехать, а не шашечки, его удовлетворит вопрос, опубликованный другим участником.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а зачем менеджер или модератор? я сам могу создать дополнительный аккаунт и проделать действия, описанные в моём предыдущем комментарии. С основного аккаунта нечестно, ибо получу репутацию (независимо от того, положительную или отрицательную) за чужой вопрос.

Comment: @СашаЧерных я думал, вы рассчитываете на последующее объединение учетных записей. Да всё равно не нужно, это бессмысленная работа. Если можете оформить хороший вопрос, который наплюсуют - публикуйте от себя. Нет - нет.