# Как лучше ответить на вопрос, который может подразумевать несколько способов решения проблемы?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

Допустим, задан вопрос, который может иметь разные варианты ответов:

> Как в вашей стране добираются из пункта А в пункт Б? На родине я делал это на <транспорте-А>, прошу совета, каким транспортом стоит пользоваться у вас.

Один из ответов содержит следующее:

> Вы можете добраться на <транспорте-Б>, но лучше это сделать с помощью <транспорта-В>.

Автор ответа считает, что отвечать на вопрос "как это можно сделать с помощью <транспорта-В> и почему так будет лучше?" не стоит, а нужно для этого задавать отдельный вопрос.

Хотелось бы узнать, как считает сообщество: есть ли необходимость приводить сразу самый лучший вариант решения проблемы, или же стоит выносить это как отдельный вопрос? То есть, различаются ли вопросы "какой прямой аналог" и "какой лучший аналог", если важен лишь результат?

---

**UPDATE:** вопрос не является общим, и различия условий, в которых происходят действия, не важны. Важен лишь результат, которого необходимо достичь.

---

**UPDATE:** моё скромное мнение:

1. Если важно лишь достичь результата, то лучше в ответе привести лучший способ решения проблемы. При желании автора ответа можно объяснить, почему именно этот способ лучший. Также при желании, или при каких-либо существенных различиях (например, предыдущий способ лучший, но к нему есть претензии, или же не всегда он может подойти, или что-то еще) - можно указать дополнительные способы решения проблемы.
2. Если вопрос слишком общий, не содержит нужных критериев для ответа или что-то ещё: стоит сказать, что есть необходимость дополнить вопрос и указать возможный вариант решения. Данный момент указан [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy) и с ним я полностью согласен.
3. Если же ответ корректен, но подразумевает несколько равносильных вариантов ответа, каждый из которых подходит - можно привести лишь один, либо несколько, чтобы дать автору возможность выбора.

Comment: `Б`, но лучше `В` вообще, как-то нелогично. Логично или `A`, но лучше `B` (если `A` тоже подходит, поскольку `A` упоминается в вопросе), или сразу -- лучше всего `B`, а уже дальше альтернативные, но в чем-то ущербные варианты.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, конкретный пример на so вопроса, а не на "транспорт А, транспорт Б".

Comment: @AK пожалуйста: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657255/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-linux

Comment: @PeterSamokhin Есть батник в винде, а есть настройка в службах ОС windows "Действие при сбое службы". Есть скрипт на баше и есть системдэ для работы со службами. Автор изначально задавал кривой вопрос с непонятными условиями и критериями лучшего, а уж какой логикой руководствовался при простановке галки -- тем более непонятно. Просто повезло, что сразу закрывашки не прилетели. Делать из этого кейса какие-то далеко идущие выводы бесполезно.

Answer (score 3):

Действия в порядке увеличения различий в решениях:

- Перечислить все пути, если различия небольшие.
- Дать каждому решению по отдельному ответу.
- Закрыть вопрос как слишком общий.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin "Ваш ответ уже близок к моему мнению" -- а почему вы не хотите дать свой вариант ответа и посмотреть, какое будет к нему отношение сообщества? Плюсики, минусики, все дела.

Comment: Отнюдь. Разные условия - разные вопросы, ведь ответ может в корне поменяться (если же условия незначительно изменены - перечислить все, как я и предложил).

Comment: @PeterSamokhin И снова к вопросу, как выбрать лучший, если условия неважны и критериев нет. Победили все пятеро, все пятеро решили проблему. Кто лучший?

Comment: Парни, переходите в комменты к своему ответу, а лучше сразу в чат, пока модеры не проснулись.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, т.е. ваши комментарии тут не выглядят, как попытка доказать кому-то свою правоту? Вы спрашивали, как добиться того же, что и в батнике - правильный ответ - цикл в sh. Лучше или хуже использование менеджеров служб невозможно понять, исходя из текста вопроса.

Answer (score -1):

> Вы можете добраться на <транспорте-Б>, но лучше это сделать с помощью

Очень часто это соседствует с [проблемой XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy), не об этом ли речь?

> Как лучше ответить на вопрос ... который может иметь разные варианты ответов

Нажать кнопку "Тревога" и выбрать "Необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ" :)

Также см. смежные топики на мете:

- [Неправильное объединение двух разных ответов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3556/) (писать ли два разных ответа как разные сообщения или объединять в одно)
- [Два или несколько вопросов в одном](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3169/) (когда один вопрос слишком далеко уходит от заданного и перерастает в другой -- отвечать в этой же теме или создавать новый топик)
- [Изменение вопроса - подмена или дополнение?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2297/) (когда вопрос заредактируют так, что полностью меняется вопрос и ответы обессмысливаются)

PS Немного про сложности выбора лучшего решения [раз](http://timestep.ru/2010/12/23/matrica-prinyatiya-reshenijj), [два](https://habrahabr.ru/post/189626/)...

Update. По примеру топика в апдейте вопроса:

Есть батник в винде, а есть настройка в службах ОС windows "Действие при сбое службы". Есть скрипт на баше и есть системдэ для работы со службами.

> у вас в вопросе батник. Его эквивалент в Linux — сценарий для bash.

Автор изначально задавал кривой вопрос с непонятными условиями и критериями лучшего, а уж какой логикой руководствовался при простановке галки -- тем более непонятно. Просто повезло, что сразу закрывашки не прилетели. Делать из этого кейса какие-то далеко идущие выводы бесполезно.

> То есть, различаются ли вопросы "какой прямой аналог" и "какой лучший
>   аналог", если важен лишь результат?

Когда только задаётся вопрос - никакой разницы, по мере добавления ответов знания автора вопроса увеличиваются и могут привести к любому результату -- как к тому, что ему ответят в том же вопросе или посоветуют задать другой вопрос или отредактировать ответ.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin И как вы будете выбирать из пяти ответов "у нас добираются вот так", какой из них наиболее правильный? Это будет произвол автора вопроса, который выберет на его усмотрение "правильный" способ. Скажем, ориентируясь на "кажется, ваши условия ближе всего к моим".

Comment: @PeterSamokhin "лучше указывать наилучший из них" -- лучший **по каким критериям**, если автор их не сформулировал вопросе? Каждый отвечающий будет додумывать за автора вопроса критерии. "Хороший вопрос -- половина ответа" (С)

Comment: @PeterSamokhin Блажен, кто верует... Даже если вы сформулируете всего лишь три критерия (и особенно не такие однозначные, как "число строк кода", а скажем, "простота поддержки и расширения"), то выбор лучшего решения возможен в настолько субъективных условиях (на основе ТОЧНОЙ матрицы весов каждого критерия, а не на ранжировании по убыванию критериев), что говорить о объективности можно только с очень высокой натяжкой. Обычно получится, что одно решение лучше по такому-то параметру, другое -- по другому. Итоговый выбор -- волюнтаризм автора вопроса.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin "В описанном мной случае всё обстоит иначе" пиведите, пожалуйста, конкретный пример на so вопроса, а не на "транспорт А, транспорт Б". Слишком голосовно у вас всё -- держите какой-то кейс в голове и приводите абстрактные примеры. Вам уже второй человек пишет, что подобного рода вопрос в реальной практике на ruso будет закрыт как too abroad, конкретные примеры в очереди модерирования топиков.

Comment: Причину закрытия "Необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ" нужно применять при невозможности дать хотя бы один объективный ответ. А не при наличии аж двух решающих проблему вариантов. :)